# Type parameter with type argument in C# Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I want to use a type parameter with type argument in generics in c# like this:

```
public class ClassB {}
public class ClassA<T>: IList<T<ClassB>> {}
```

Is it possible doing something like this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. What would you expect `IList<T<ClassB>>` to be?

Comment: Waht are you "really" trying to do ?

Comment: There is no way you could declare a type parameter as a generic type definition.

Comment: It seems that I faced this problem because I made a mistake in analyzing the problem.
Thank you, everybody

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, it seems you can't yet, even using `where` clauses: the compiler refuses all `T<ClassB>` and `IList<T1<T2>>`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0307

Example:

```
public class ClassA<T1, T2> : IList<T1<T2>> // implementation request refused
  where T2 : ClassB
{
}

public class ClassA<T, T1, T2> : IList<T>
  where T : T1<T2> // constraint refused
  where T2 : ClassB
{
}
```

> Cannot use parameter of type T1 with arguments of type

It might be interesting to be able to do such a thing.

Comment: If you constrain `T1` to an *actual* generic type, then this compiles fine.

Comment: "After trying many things, it seems you can't yet" - of course you can't - not yet, but *never*, because C# Generics are not like C++ Templates: C# generic parameter arguments must be closed over the (sub)set of possible constrained types, C++ template parameter arguments don't have this limitation.

Comment: @Dai Of course, but it is not, as written, what the OP want, it seems, unless there is an error in the question.

Comment: It seems that I faced this problem because I made a mistake in analyzing the problem. Thank you, everybody